# Erro ao executar servidor do IONIC

Tags: angular, ionic, typescript

Essa semana peguei um freela feito com uma versão mais antiga do IONIC, um código ruim e tals, só tenho que dar manutenção. Porém não consigo executar o servidor. Toda vez que tento, obtenho o seguinte erro mostrado na imagem[image: Imagem com erro]

Comment: Tenta rodar assim: `npm run ionic:serve`

Answer (score 0):

Pra ajudar tu pode postar a versão do Ionic que o projeto foi desenvolvido, versão do angular que está rodando no package e pode verificar se não há necessidade de uma versão anterior do node também.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se esta instalado o rxjs projeto, caso n esteja instale-o
com o seguinte comando **npm install rxjs --save**

Comment: Ele parece estar usando ionic3, já que esta usando ionic-app-scripts, portanto instalar o rxjs não vai resolver nada e nem serve para nada relacionado a isto, simplesmente é provavel que ou ele instalou uma versão antiga do ionic-cli (que é global e não do projeto) ou a instalação do ionic-cli quebrou, ou muito mais provavel é que seja erro em um .ts que esta de fato pegando uma var undefined.